# Create a vector or a list with the content of several columns

Tags: r, vector

I want to create a vector or a list in a dataset concatenating the scores of several columns in another dataset.

I can do it like this:

```
my_vec <- c(x$v1, x$v2, x$v3...)
```

But I would need like 60 lines of code. I am pretty sure there is another way of doing it. When I try this:

```
my_vec <- c(x$v1:x$v644)
```

I get this error message

```
Warning messages:
1: In t$`1`:t$`644` :
  numerical expression has 20 elements: only the first used
```

My dataset looks like this

```
x <- read.table(
  text = "  v1   v2  V3   
  0      1     0
  1      0     1
  0      0     0
  0      0     1
  1      0     0",
  header = TRUE
)
```

And as an output I would like just a vector with values for each column one after the other, like this:

```
my_vec <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Could please provide a sample data?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to do the table correctly, is that understandable, DJV?

Comment: you could use `unname(unlist(x))`

Comment: also that `read.table()` strategy is a great way to share data in forum settings like SO

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste()`. If they are all in the same `data.frame`, you can create a new column with the concatenation.

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(conc = paste(a, b, c))
```

Output:

```
  a b c  conc
1 a e g a e g
2 b f h b f h
3 c g i c g i
4 d h j d h j
```

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:4], 
                 b = letters[5:8], 
                 c = letters[7:10])
```

## Edit

If they are in diffrent vectors, you can do something like this:

```
a <- letters[1:4]
b <- letters[5:8] 
c <- letters[7:10]

reduce(list(a, b, c), union)
```

Output:

```
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

Comment: Thank you! They are not in the same dataset. And I do not want another column, I want it to be like a list in a separate object. In you example, the output that I would like to get would be a list containing: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, g, h, i, j, etc. I am sorry if I haven't explained myself correctly...

Comment: No worries, please see my edit. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I have the same warning message when your using paste... Do I need to name all the columns one by one? Isn't there a cleaner way of doing it? THANKS

Comment: Nope, still not working... =( Same warning. I am doing this df<-mutate(conc = paste(x$v1:xv2)) ##to avoid putting all numbers up to 644

Comment: what warning do you get?

Comment: Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In t$`1`:t$`644` :
  numerical expression has 20 elements: only the first used

Comment: Thanks for your edit!! The error is stil in the same part. I need a way to replace "(a,b,c)" by "(a:c)" without getting that warning... Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I was late on your edits, hehe. That is better! THANKS! But I still makes another dataset, rather than lists. And in any case, it makes me do at least thirty lines of code...  Isn't there a more proper way of doing it?

Comment: How would you like to specify your input vectors? are they randomly named? are they the same?

Comment: No, they are not random. They come from a dataset that has scores in it. The scores are 0s and 1s. So I need to pick the 0s and 1s in each column and put them together in a string/a list/a vector...

Comment: Are they all part of `data.frame` x? where each column is your vector to concatenate?

Answer (score 0):

could a simple solution like

```
my_vec = x[, 1:644]
```

work?

Comment: Nope, that just reproduced the original dataset. But thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *x* is a data.frame:

```
> as.vector(unlist( split(as.matrix(x), row(x)) ))
```

The output might be a vector of characters, however you can make the values numeric again using *as.numeric()*.

Credit:

Got the idea using the following post as a guide

[How to split a R data frame into vectors (unbind)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221755/how-to-split-a-r-data-frame-into-vectors-unbind)

**EDIT:**

Using your example data, we get the following:

```
x <- read.table(
  text = "  v1   v2  V3   
  0      1     0
  1      0     1
  0      0     0
  0      0     1
  1      0     0",
  header = TRUE
)

> as.vector(unlist( split(as.matrix(x), row(x)) ))
[1] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: I will try this. I could solve it by using a double loop in Excel but I still want to do it through R. Thanks!